# Attaching play button on thumbnail

Tags: css

I want to attach play button (made in CSS) on my video thumbnail, but I've problem. On small devices it looks like:

[image]

But If I want to broaden my window it looks like:

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe2Vi.png): 
There is any option to set it rigidly in center of this thumbnail no matter if I broaden my window or not?

```css
    .video img
    {
     width: 100%;
    }
    
    .play-button-outer {
      margin: 25% auto;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: #fe6a00;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: relative;
      top: -185px;
      left: 20px;
    }
    
    .play-button {
      margin: 0 auto;
      top: 30%;
      position: relative;  
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 9px 0 12px 17px;
      border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FFF;
      opacity: .75;
    }
    
    .play-button-outer:hover .play-button {
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="video">
   <img src="img/video-thumb.png">
   <div class="play-button-outer">
      <div class="play-button"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

I have made the position of the `.play-button-outer` **absolute** and

```
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
```

the above lines will ensure that, it will always remain in the center (vertically and horizontally) of the video.

Also you need to make te position of the `.video` **relative**

```css
.video img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.video {
  position: relative;
}

.play-button-outer {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fe6a00;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.play-button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 30%;
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 9px 0 12px 17px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FFF;
  opacity: .75;
}

.play-button-outer:hover .play-button {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200">
  <div class="play-button-outer">
    <div class="play-button"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is a re-usable, standard way of centering something both vertically and horizontally:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%; /* this percentage relates to the parent element */
left: 50%; /* this percentage relates to the parent element */
transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* this percentage relates to the element itself */
```

Please note that, for this to work the way you'd expect, the parent container needs to be positioned (that is, it cannot have `position: static;` which is the default value).

```css
.video img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.play-button-outer {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fe6a00;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .75;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
}

.play-button {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 9px 0 12px 17px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 2px), -50%);
}

.play-button-outer:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/1600/900">
  <div class="play-button-outer">
    <div class="play-button"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!